# Replace specific instance of item in string with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to build a parser that will replace a specific instance of a string. So for example I have a string that is `sn+sn+sn*9`, and I want to only replace the third instance of `sn` How can I do this with regex?

I have tried

```
var expression = "sn+sn+sn*9";
var regex = new Regex("sn");
expression = regex.Replace("sn",4.ToString());
//expression = regex.Replace("sn",4.ToString(),1,2);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x = 0;
string repl = "ANYTHING";
string s = Regex.Replace("sn+sn+sn*9", "sn", m => (++x) == 3 ? repl : m.Value);
```

**Explanation**

The `x` variable is used to track the occurrence of sought text. As soon as Regex finds third occurrence, the [MatchEvaluator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator) delegate replaces this string with whatever is in `repl` variable. Otherwise, it just returns the same found string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option, which uses the following regex pattern:

```
(?<=.*?\bsn\b.*?\bsn\b.*?)\bsn\b
```

This pattern literally says to replace `sn`, as a single term, when we have already seen two `sn` terms previously in the string.  I use the replacement `blah` in the sample code below, though you may use any value you wish.

```
var term = @"sn";
var replacement = "blah";
var expression = term + "+" + term + "+" + term + "*9";
var pattern = @"(?<=.*?\b" + term + @"\b.*?\b" + term + @"\b.*?)\b" + term + @"\b";
var exp_trim = Regex.Replace(expression, @pattern, replacement);
Console.WriteLine(exp_trim);

sn+sn+blah*9
```

### Demo

Comment: thank you, is there a way to create an extension method to pass in the instance number and the string to replace?

Comment: @JamTay317 I updated my answer to use `term` and `replacement` as parameters.  You may easily build a method around this, if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method using the index and length of the match

```
           string expression = "sn+sn+sn*9";
            Regex regex = new Regex("sn");
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(expression);
            expression = expression.Substring(0, matches[2].Index) + "4".ToString() + expression.Substring(matches[2].Index + matches[2].Length);
```